# Image quantization algorithm with clustering properties

Tags: algorithm

Most quantizer algorithms reduce the number of colors in an image, but the colors appear as dots throughout the image. When quantizing images which we know have a fixed number of colors, say, logos, it is desirable that similarly colored pixels are clustered together. Is there a quantizing algorithm that is suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean shift!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/TUZEL1/MeanShift.pdf
and many more links...

[This one](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2007/11/mean-shift-segmentation-in-matlab/) even has examples showing exactly (I hope) what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a new user here, and don't seem to have enough privileges to vote you up.